# How to run Version-based URL services in Ready-API along with some VIP URL services in the same test-suite?

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I have two services in test-suite, one with VIP URL and other with Version-based URL. Second services has a parameter depend on first service response.
When I run Test-Suite, first service with VIP URL was passed and second service was Failed and giving response as 404.
How can I run my test-suite, one service with VIP URL & second service with Version-based URL in Ready-API?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Property Transfer test step after the call to your first service to pull the required value out of the response. Set a test-case level property, called say `serviceVersion`. Then, use that property as the parameter of your second property with `${#TestCase#serviceVersion}`

For more details about properties, see:

- [Working with TestSteps](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-teststeps.html)
- [Property Expansion](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/properties/expansion.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got solution for the above question. We need to enable close connections after request in Preferences tab.